# model e controller no codeigniter para fazer insert no firebird usando generator

Tags: codeigniter, firebird, sql-insert, generators

Sou novo no codeigniter e preciso definir meu controller e model, de forma qual ao chamar a model `inserir()`, o controller leve a última ID do generator de cada tabela que se quer fazer o insert. Vou dar um exemplo:

**controller:**

```
public function salvar(){
    if($this->input->post('action') == 'cadastrar'){
        $dados = array (
            'COD_CIDADES' => '',
            'DESCRICAO' => $this->input->post('cidade'),
            'UF' => $this->input->post('uf'),
            'CEP' => $this->input->post('cep'),         
            'COD_SITUACAO' => '0',
            'ISS' => 'null',
            'COD_PAIS' => '1',
            'COD_IBGE' => $this->input->post('ibge')
        );

        $this->crud_model->inserir($tabela, $dados);

        redirect('cidades/index');

    }
```

**model:**

```
public function inserir($tabela, $dados_banco){                     
    return $this->db->insert($tabela, $dados_banco);
}
```

Nesse caso, o campo `COD_CIDADES` teria que receber o último `ID (GEN_CIDADES)`, sei que daria pra fazer uma consulta assim:
`"select gen_id(GEN_CIDADES, 0) as COD from RDB"."$"."DATABASE`", mas não sei como estruturar isso de forma que possa usar o model `insert()` para todas os meus insert´s.

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que você tenha uma coluna 'id' no seu bd. Adicione mais um argumento a sua função:

```
   public function inserir($tabela, $dados_banco ,$key ){                     

        $query = $this->get($table);
        $row = $query->last_row();

        $dados_banco[$key] = $row->id;

         return $this->db->insert($tabela, $dados_banco);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Também trabalho com Codeigniter e Firebird e a forma que encontrei de resolver esta situação é criar um método no model que retorne o ultimo generator:

```
public function pega_prox_id()
{
    return $this->db->query("SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_TB_TV_PEDIDO_ID, 1) FROM RDB\$DATABASE;")->result();
}
```

o número 1 após a vírgula indica que ele tem que acrescentar mais um no resultado que ele pegou do generator.